# alternate two wav files into 1 single one using sox and bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sox

I'm using linux and bash I have two files filea.wav and fileb.wav which are both 1 second long. I would like to join 4000 of them so I will get 1 large file that is an hour long that has the two files alternating.

Example: of what the 1 hour single file would look like
filea.wav fileb.wav filea.wav fileb.wav filea.wav fileb.wav .....

I know I can use sox to create and repeat a file

```
sox filea.wav file1hour.wav repeat 4000
```

but how can I have it so two files alternate back and forth and still get 1 single file using sox?

Comment: 4000 seconds is, of course, 1 hour, 6 minutes, and 40 seconds' duration.

Comment: Ollie!!! is that you it's me Renrick the crazy Co-op guy from the days of Vivo software, talk about a small world. I just wanted a round number so I chose 4000. Testing out some neuroacoustic audio files created in octave/matlab and sox works great for speed to join them together ;-)

Comment: Hey Rick, it's me.  Nice to see you online! Neuroacoustics sounds like fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sox filea.wav fileb.wav long.wav
sox long.wav file1hour.wav repeat 1800
rm long.wav
```

More details on how to use `sox(1)`: http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

Comment: I don't know, perhaps -- I went for what would be easiest to read.

Comment: another person sent me an email and said another way to do this is by "sox filea.wav fileb.wav hour.wav repeat 1800"